# Submit a form in the background of my Node.Js app using AJAX or Socket.IO, get results, update the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, socket.io

I would like to submit a form with a text in the background of my Node.Js/express app in the background using

```
document.querySelector('#submitform').addEventListener('submit',   function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // 1. i quietly submit my form to the /post url but without reloading the page
   // 2. i receive some information from that url about the message + updated file
   // 3. i then emit an event, which sends the message + updated file to the app
   // 4. the message and the new updated file are then displayed to the user without reloading the page
});
```

The problem is that I don't know whether for `Step 1` I should use AJAX or `Socket.io`

and also - how do i make sure that `step 3` and `step 4` are only triggered after `Step 2` occurs?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using jQuery on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the submit type on your button.
2. Submit the form or values you need to send to your node js app:

   ```
   $.post(nodejsUrl, $("#formID").serialize())
   .done(function(res) {
       //3. Receive the server response, no need to emit an event
       if (res.success) {
           //4. Show the updated text
           $("#text").html(res.newText);
   }
   else {
       alert(res.error);
   }})
   .fail(function(res) {
       alert("Server Error: " + res.status + " " + res.statusText);
   });
   ```

I think there is definitely no need to use sockets unless you are editing this in "real time" with other users or based on backend  actions or triggers.

Comment: Thank you! What does `.done` specifically respond to actually? Does it need a specific answer from the `/post` page?

Comment: just an http code lets say. The res parameters in both done and fail functions are the data/text sent from the server